# \justifying is not working with \usepackage[document]{ragged2e}. How to justify these lines?

Tags: justification

[image]

I tried many code but it never works on this. Don't know how to do this. I've used \justifying, \justify...

Comment: Hi! Welcome! Please notice that little red box with a 96 in it on the upper right(-ish) part: you have **ninety-six** errors in your code. Probably one of those is related to your problem, but it's impossible to say which one. Please click on that box, read the first error message, correct it, recompile, repeat until *all* of them are corrected and the block is yellow or green... notice that you have to start from the first one, the others could be a side-effect of the previous one(s).

Comment: you essentially _never_ need to use `\justifying` as that is the default, but if you get any error don't even look at the pdf, it is not intended to be usable, just an aid to debugging.

Comment: we can not debug an image, make a small complete document that is shpwing the problem and add it to your question as text in a code block (`{}` in the editor)